# how can we set custom detents for sheetPresentationController in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios15, uisheetpresentationcontroller

from iOS 16 we can set custom detents in sheetPresentationController but is there any way or alternative to archive same thing in iOS 15 as well.

```
  if let sheet = objVC?.sheetPresentationController {
               
  if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
     sheet.detents = [
     .custom { _ in
      return 550
     }
   ]
    } else {
       sheet.detents = [.medium(),.large()]
    }
       sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
       sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
       sheet.preferredCornerRadius = 22
       sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = true
       sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
       sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
       sheet.selectedDetentIdentifier = .medium        
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

It was not possible back in iOS 15. Check [this](https://sarunw.com/posts/bottom-sheet-in-ios-15-with-uisheetpresentationcontroller/#detent) article.

Apart from your question...

I saw this while searching for another question: how to set **custom** **largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier**, maybe I'm not alone with this problem and here is how to achieve desired behaviour:

1. Create your own custom extension

```
extension UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier {
    static let customHeight = UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier("customHeight")
}
```

2. Add custom height to the detents array:

```
sheet.detents = [.custom(identifier: .customHeight) { _ in
    return 80
}, .large()]
```

3. After that you're able to use your own custom detent:

```
sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .customHeight
```